# Request object or current url (url_for) access inside classes in lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get a string of the current URL (either from the request object or a call to url_for) inside a class I wrote that resides in my projects lib directory.  How do I do this?  I tried to

```
request.url
```

and the request object is not accessible from within my class.

Answer (score 0):

The `request.url` is only accessible from inside a controller. I would suggest that the url is a parameter you hand down to your class (at construction-time or when calling the method). This will keep the concerns nicely separated.

Hope this helps.